# Individual blog for each member

Tags: members

I need to allow members to create their own blogs.
Is it possible? If yes, so how can I realize such ability?

Comment: First check the licensing from EllisLab - it has language that doesn't allow creation of a "hosted blogging platform".  You may need to email sales to clarify with your intended purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to have a system that allows you to determine the author_id of the current blog and use the `author_id=""` parameter. You can have them build profiles using [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/profile-edit/) or [ZooVisiter](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/).

However, as Michael said above, make sure it's fine with ExpressionEngine and complies with their policies.